# What are the files with the extensions .1, .2 or .3 in the data directory

Tags: postgresql

Why are there files ending in .1 .2 .3 in my PostgreSQL database folder?

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1073741824 Oct 11 09:32 412rw95.2
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   67100672 Oct 11 09:32 41295.3
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1073741824 Oct 11 09:07 41296
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1073741824 Oct 11 07:27 41296.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) describes this:

> When a table or index exceeds 1 GB, it is divided into gigabyte-sized segments. The first segment's file name is the same as the filenode; subsequent segments are named filenode.1, filenode.2, etc.